# sharepoint as authentication provider

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, authentication

Is it possible to use sharepoint as an authentication provider?

This is my setup:

Server A -> IIS web application loading custom dll's for different user providers

Server B -> Sharepoint 2007

Server C & D -> Multiple AD's

Sharepoint is configured to use multiple AD's as user provider

This is what I want to achieve:

A user enters his sharepoint credentials in the web application, this automaticly loads the dll (which I need to create)
This dll then forwards the credentials somehow to sharepoint and retreives some sort of user object.
The dll parses the sharepoint user object to it's own class and sends it back to the webapp.
Is this possible? If yes, what would be the best way to do this? I know sharepoint has webservices etc but I don't know if this could work.

All servers are in the same network, accessed locally so passing the credentials isn't a big problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UserGroup Web Service**

Did you consider using the UserGroup Web Service, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcusergroup.aspx.

Available at http://sharepointserver/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx

It has the GetUserInfo method, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcusergroup.usergroup.getuserinfo.aspx

**Authentication Web Service**

There is also the Authentication Web Service, but it only return the login result, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcauthentication.aspx

Great for checking the validity of a user anyway.

Available at http://sharepointserver/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx

Comment: This might work indeed, I could first check the validity on a user to check their credentials, if valid, I can get the user details to pass to the web application. Thanks for the post!